# TypeORM: Make a select request with relation and where

Tags: typeorm

I do an API with NestJS and the ORM TypeORM

I have for entity:

User

RelationshipType

UserRelationshipType (with user and relationshiptype ForeignKey)

And Relationship (with userRelationshipType ForeignKey)

And need to find all the relationship, but from specific user
So I need somewhere to declare "user.id = id"

I have done that with createQueryBuilder

```
this.repo
    .createQueryBuilder('relationship')
    .innerJoinAndSelect(
      'relationship.userRelationshipType',
      'userRelationshipType',
    )
    .innerJoinAndSelect(
      'userRelationshipType.user',
      'user',
      'user.id = :id',
      { id: id },
    )
    .innerJoinAndSelect(
      'userRelationshipType.relationshipType',
      'relationshipType',
    )
    .getMany()
```

And it's work
But I'm not happy because I want to do all my request with the .find or findOne

And when I'm doing

```
this.repo.find({

  relations: [

    'userRelationshipType',

    'userRelationshipType.user',

    'userRelationshipType.relationshipType',

  ],

  where: {userRelationshipType: {user: {id: id}}}

});
```

that doesn't work... but in the doc it's say to do that...
I can find all, but can apply the good where condition (or join condition)
Have you an idea?

I have tried with join also, but i'm a little bit lost

Thanks :)

Comment: you cannot currently filter by relations, see https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3890

Answer (score 0):

if you use class validator, then you can make it easily..

--> provide relation between two tables.
--> Give @exclude for what are the field you dont want to select in model.
--> dont forget to mention to import class validator package.
thank you.

---

Here example for you

```
 @Exclude()
    @Column({ name: 'password' })
    public password: string;
```